# What is a good epithet for someone who follows the rules regardless of good sense

Tags: nouns, adjectives

'Vogon' is a good one but not if you don't have the right cultural background.
"Robot" and "drone" work.
Can anyone think of any more?

Comment: Not heard "Vogon" used in this sense. Is it a reference to the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy?

Comment: It is indeed ;>

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be only british but it is good

> **jobsworth**
>   NOUN
>   British  informal
>   An official who upholds petty rules
>   even at the expense of humanity or common sense.
>
> ‘parks abound with jobsworths who delight in yelling that you can't do
>   that without special permission’

It originates from the phrase **"sorry mate that is more than my jobs worth"** when asking to be allowed to do something like walk 2 steps across the grass rather than 1/2 mile around the path.

**person 1 :** please can we come in I know you don't open for another 2 mins but my granny is about to collapse and needs somewhere to sit.
**guy on door:** sorry mate that is more than my jobs worth

**person 1 to granny**: that guy is such a jobsworth.

---

I don't think it is coincidental that both my answer and your suggestion are British in origin.

Comment: It is not. I am also a Brit (living in South Wales, you?)

Comment: @JacobStewart North Yorkshire

Answer (score 2):

**stickler**

stickler
noun [ C ] US ​  /ˈstɪk·lər/
​
someone who believes in closely following rules or in maintaining a high standard of behavior:
He was a stickler when it came to office manners.

Also, more limited in scope, **martinet**

mar·ti·net
/ˌmärtnˈet/
noun
a strict disciplinarian, especially in the armed forces.
"the woman in charge was a martinet who treated all those beneath her like children"
synonyms:   disciplinarian, slave driver, stickler for discipline, taskmaster, taskmistress, authoritarian, tyrant; drill sergeant

Comment: The question called for a word for someone who follows rules *regardless of good sense*. Stickler seems more positive in connotation.

Comment: Martinet is perfect though.